# BinaryReader EndOfStreamException when BaseStream.Position < BaseStream.Length

Tags: c#, binaryreader

While using a BinaryReader, how is it possible that I get an EndOfStreamException on `ReadUInt16()` when `BaseStream.Position` is equal to 20 and `BaseStream.Length` is equal to 174? I can't find anything in the docs to indicate how this can occur.

```
EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.
System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer (Int32 numBytes) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/BinaryReader.cs:119)
System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadUInt16 () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/BinaryReader.cs:513)
Chunk.SaveChunk () (at Assets/Scripts/Chunk.cs:293)
```

Here is the exact data I believe to be in the stream. This data was retrieved from the program Hex Editor Neo while Visual Studio was halted at a breakpoint on the line of the exception.

```
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 a0 00 00 00 00 00
ff ff 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 10 0c 10 02 00 00 0c
00 0b 01 03 01 00 00 0c 03 04 02 0d 02 00 00 0e
03 01 01 0d 01 00 01 0e 03 03 01 09 01 00 01 0e
0c 0f 02 04 02 00 04 0c 03 06 01 01 01 00 04 0c
04 0c 02 0c 02 00 04 0e 04 0a 01 05 01 00 04 0e
09 07 02 03 02 00 0a 0c 03 06 02 01 02 00 0a 0e
03 06 01 01 01 00 0b 0c 00 05 02 03 02 00 0b 0e
00 05 01 03 01 00 0b 0e 09 01 01 01 01 00 0b 0e
0a 05 02 02 02 00 0c 0e 09 04 02 01 02 00 0e 0e
04 02 01 04 01 00 0e 0e 08 02 02 01 02 00
```

**Edit:** Code from opening the stream up until the exception.

```
public void SaveChunk()
{
    lock (chunkDataLock)
    {
        FileStream readStream = File.Open("GameData/chunkdata.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write);
        FileStream writeStream = File.Open("GameData/chunkdata.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(readStream))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream))
        {
            //reader.BaseStream.Length == 174 here
            if (reader.BaseStream.Length == 0)
            {
                writer.Write((ushort)0);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            }

            // 0, 0, 0
            int[] regionPos = GetRegionFromChunkPosition(chunkPosX, chunkPosY, chunkPosZ);

            // numRegions = 1
            ushort numRegions = reader.ReadUInt16();
            writer.BaseStream.Position += 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < numRegions; i++)
            {
                // 0, 0, 0
                short regXPos = reader.ReadInt16(), regYPos = reader.ReadInt16(), regZPos = reader.ReadInt16();
                // numChunksPosition = 8
                long numChunksPosition = reader.BaseStream.Position;
                // numChunks = 1
                ushort numChunks = reader.ReadUInt16();
                // regionLengthPosition = 10
                long regionLengthPosition = reader.BaseStream.Position;
                // regionLength = 160
                uint regionLength = reader.ReadUInt32();

                uint newRegionLength = 0;
                writer.BaseStream.Position += 12;

                // At this point reader and writer both have BaseStream.Position of 14

                // True
                if (regXPos == regionPos[0] && regYPos == regionPos[1] && regZPos == regionPos[2])
                {
                    bool chunkFound = false;
                    for (ushort j = 0; j < numChunks; j++)
                    {
                        // 0, -1, 0
                        short xPos = reader.ReadInt16(), yPos = reader.ReadInt16(), zPos = reader.ReadInt16();
                        writer.BaseStream.Position += 6;

                        // Exception occurs on this line.
                        // at this point, reader.BaseStream.Position = 20
                        // and reader.BaseStream.Length = 174
                        ushort numVoxelGroups = reader.ReadUInt16();
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind including the code for opening the stream, setting up the BinaryReader and reading data from it.

Comment: Are you reading before you received all the data?  You are reading binary data so how do you know that you got all the data?  If you are using a Memory stream as input make sure after you fill the memory stream to set position to zero before reading.  Both are very common errors.

Comment: @ZiggZagg I have edited to include the code from when I open the stream to when the exception occurs.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure if this is still relevant with a FileStream using File.Open to obtain the stream. I am certainly setting position to zero before reading though.

Comment: You're reading and writing to the same file at the same time. That's almost certainly the cause of the problem - and easy to verify by just changing the code to read from one file and write to a different one.

Comment: You cannot move the position of the write stream without writing data.  The following line will not work :  writer.BaseStream.Position += 6;

Comment: @DaisyShipton My testing indicates that I can indeed read/write simultaneously as long as I Flush() after each write. In fact, in this particular case I haven't written anything yet at the time of the exception.

Comment: But it's *at least* a potential source of complexity. Have you *tried* using a separate file instead? That would give valuable diagnostic information apart from anything else. It would also really help if you could reduce this to a [mcve] - there's a lot going on in your code that I suspect is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @jdweng My external testing indicates that writer.BaseStream.Position += x does in fact work. However, MSDN docs say "Using the underlying stream while reading or while using the BinaryReader can cause data loss and corruption. For example, the same bytes might be read more than once, bytes might be skipped, or character reading might become unpredictable."

Do you know of an alternative way to write to a particular location of a binary file?

Comment: Create a byte array and write the the array.  Then save the array at the end.  You can use BitConvert to Read and write values.  If you do not know the size of the byte array the use List<byte> so you can add to the size.